# TimePickerDialog runs twice

Tags: android, nested, local, inner-classes, android-timepicker

> Android Studio: with single textView and single TimePickerDialog as a nested local class.
>   **When the TimePickerDialog is tapped and onTimeSet runs TWICE.**

Tapped once, it should only run once. (ie. the "toast" shouldn't display PartyTime Set:0 then immediately afterwards PartyTime Set:1 )
 
 **Why twice?... How can I make it run only once?**

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {
    int n_Count;
    SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm");
    Calendar calPartyTime = Calendar.getInstance();
    int ct_hourParty = calPartyTime.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY); 
    int ct_minuteParty = calPartyTime.get(Calendar.MINUTE);

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        TimePickerDialog timePickerParty = new TimePickerDialog(this, new TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener() {
            @Override
            public void onTimeSet(TimePicker timePicker, int selectedHour, int selectedMinute) {

                calPartyTime.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, selectedHour);
                calPartyTime.set(Calendar.MINUTE, selectedMinute);

                String date = dateFormat.format(calPartyTime.getTime());

                TextView tv_PartyTime = (TextView) findViewById((R.id.partyTimeTextView));
                tv_PartyTime.setText(date);

                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Party Time Set!:" + n_Count , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                n_Count++;
            }
        }, ct_hourParty, ct_minuteParty, true);

        timePickerParty.setTitle("Set Party UTC (HH:MM)");
        timePickerParty.show();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can add some logic like this i have used (use a boolean variable and check its value -

```
public static class DatePickerFragment extends DialogFragment implements OnDateSetListener {

boolean mFirst = true;

@Override
public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Use the current date as the default date in the picker
    final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
    int year = c.get(Calendar.YEAR);
    int month = c.get(Calendar.MONTH);
    int day = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);

    // Create a new instance of DatePickerDialog and return it
    return new DatePickerDialog(getActivity(), this, year, month, day);
}

public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int month, int day) {
    if (mFirst) {
        mFirst = false;
        // Do something with the date chosen by the user

        currentYear = year;
        currentMonth = month;
        currentDay = day;

        DialogFragment newFragment2 = new TimePickerFragment();
        newFragment2.show(getFragmentManager(), "timePicker");
    }
}
}
```

Hope this helps :)

Comment: Added logic does help... thank you!...though I'd like to understand "why" the additional iteration of "onTimeSet" in the first place.

Comment: This is basically a known bug - https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=34833

Comment: Thank you again... Looks like time will resolve these issues, so for now, added logic is required.